# How to group buttons in qt designer

Tags: qt, button

So I want to be able to group some radio buttons into 2 groups. My current ui looks like the following:

[image: My buttons]

However, at this stage only one can be checked at a time. That is, if you select "male" and then try and select a grade, it will deselect the gender. I want to be able to group them so that someone can only select one gender and one grade.

Comment: When you say Qt, what flavour? PyQT? QML? Qt-C++  ? And it would be helpfull to include your current code for this too

Comment: Qt Creator, i am using the design mode

Comment: Do you have 2 group boxes?

Comment: No I put one set in a group box and it didn't make a difference, but then when i put both goups in seperate group boxes it worked. Thanks @Jarod42, if you want to copy and past that into an answer ill accept that as the answer so you get the credit

Answer (score 3):

You need one groupBox by group of radio buttons.

So in your case, you need 2 groupBoxes.